# How do i add the value that is in createData using @property and use that in putData

Tags: python, python-2.7, properties

```
Class Data(self):
    def __ init __(self):
        self._dictList = []

    @property
    def dictList(self):
        return self._dictList

    @dictList.setter
    def dictList(self, value):
        self._dictList.append(value)

    def putData(self):

        for value in self.dictList:
            print value

    def createData(self):

        value = 10
        self.dictList = value
```

How do i add the value that is in createData using @property and use that in putData ?

Comment: Can you showcase how you are gonna call your properties and what you are expecting ?

Comment: I wanto add that value 10 by calling setter from createData and then use that value inside putData by calling @property

Comment: Instead of doing that dictList.append(value) in createData how can i call the setter from there

Comment: Please write your class usage (how you are gonna call and use it)..
It is still unclear what you are trying to do, and showing the final result will be clearer than discussing the intermediate steps :)

Comment: How do i set the value and get the value ??

Comment: You seem to be doing it correctly (according to your code) , what is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Even if I still do not understand your expectation, let's correct what's wrong here:

- This is not how you declare a class

  ```
  Class Data(self): # incorrect
  class Data(object): # correct
  ```
- Your dict is a list ... and should not be name like a dict

Then from your comment I will propose to use heritage:

```
class Data(list): # <-- Data is now a list
```

That way you can add values like on a normal list (ie: `list[key] = value` or `list.append(value)` or `list.insert(index, value)`)
And add your custom methods like in a normal class.

Comment: I have edited the question...check there and tell me whether its right what i am doing ??